# Why does Leak Canary detect Google firebase APIs as Leaks?

Tags: firebase, leakcanary

Why does Leak Canary detect Google firebase APIs as Leaks?
When I launch an app while using firebase, it keeps on detecting memory leaks. Is there a way to stop this? Thanks.

````
┬───
│ GC Root: Global variable in native code
│
├─ com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.zza instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 634 B in 9 objects
│    zza instance of com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.
│    FirebaseAuthFallbackService
│    ↓ zza.zza
│          ~~~
╰→ com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService
​  instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.google.firebase.
​     auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService received
​     Service#onDestroy() callback)
​     Retaining 606 B in 8 objects
​     key = 7ab80331-3185-47d4-b999-118434212080
​     watchDurationMillis = 5284
​     retainedDurationMillis = 278
​     mApplication instance of com.example.app.App
​     mBase instance of android.app.ContextImpl

METADATA

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 27
Build.MANUFACTURER: iLA
LeakCanary version: 2.6
App process name: com.example.app
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=1327,misses=42351,hitRate=3%]
RandomAccess[bytes=2171000,reads=42351,travel=15377633875,range=14122402,size=17
486349]
Heap dump reason: 1 retained objects, app is not visible
Analysis duration: 16095 ms```
````

Comment: Hello, have you found the solution?

Comment: Waiting for fix from Google https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2387

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2387
Edited:

Here is the suggested workaround to ignore that small leak from the site: 

`First, disable the automatic install:`

```
<resources>
  <bool name="leak_canary_watcher_auto_install">false</bool>
</resources>
Then install LeakCanary manually in your debug application, ignoring FirebaseAuthFallbackService:

class DebugExampleApplication : ExampleApplication() {

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    val delegate = ReachabilityWatcher { watchedObject, description ->
      if (watchedObject::class.java.name != "com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService
​  instance") {
        AppWatcher.objectWatcher.expectWeaklyReachable(watchedObject, description)
      }
    }

    val watchersToInstall = AppWatcher.appDefaultWatchers(application, delegate)

    AppWatcher.manualInstall(
      application = application,
      watchersToInstall = watchersToInstall
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.